# Reset the counter for Traffic Stats Api in android

Tags: android

How to reset the counter for Traffic Stats Api. Is there any system call for that. Actually everytime, device reboot, it removes the earlier file and create new one , thus setting new counter on each reboot. Can i do it programatically from my App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry. You should not need this -- if you are trying to track the bandwidth consumed between two points in time, simply hold onto the traffic values from the start time and subtract them from the traffic values at the end time.

Comment: That won't work if the device got rebooted in between as the second value might even be lower then the first one.

Comment: @marsbear: True, but that's usually an infrequent scenario.

Comment: I honestly disagree as reboots happen usually within days. Every time the battery runs out of power the phone will boot again and the stats will be resetted.